# How to join tables to result in final table that only shows rows with the 2 same column values SQL

Tags: join, filter, google-bigquery

Let's say I have

table 1:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | july 10 |
| 2 | aug 4 |
| 3 | feb 20 |

table 2:

| ID | Date | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | july 10 | joe | 123 Howard way |
| 2 | aug 4 | kate | 456 king ave |
| 3 | feb 20 | lisa | 789 giuldford way |
| 4 | march 1 | jake | 145 smith street |
| 5 | dec 16 | robert | 6784 apple street |

I want the final table to pull all columns from table 2 but only the rows that have the same ID number and Date as table 1 therefore:

final table:

| ID | Date | Name | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | july 10 | joe | 123 Howard way |
| 2 | aug 4 | kate | 456 king ave |
| 3 | feb 20 | lisa | 789 giuldford way |

How would I do this?
I tried using an INNER JOIN and ON with a WHERE clause and that didn't work out. I received duplicates of everything. Also tried a subquery as well. Please help. I am using Standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

Simple JOIN should work!

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 
USING (ID, Date)
```

In case if Table 1 really has just those two columns that are part of Using clause - you can use also below (simply `*` instead of `t2.*`)

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 
USING (ID, Date)
```

Comment: not working im still getting duplicates :(

Comment: provide more details in your question including examples of what you call "duplicates"! note: with the sample data you provided - all works as one would expected!

Answer (score 0):

Try with Left Join with below query:

```
SELECT t1.Id,t1.Date,t2.Name,t2.Address 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.Id=t1.Id AND t2.Date=t1.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RIGHT JOIN with query below

```
SELECT t2.* FROM t2
RIGHT JOIN t1 USING (ID, Date)
```